# dlib is installed but unable to import in spyder or anaconda

Tags: python, computer-vision, anaconda, dlib

I am trying to use a library called dlib on spyder or anaconda. Since i am using windows I need c++ libraries to run dlib - such as CMake or visual studio c++.

I have installed all the libraries even the dlib through the CMD. But whenever I am importing the dlib library in spyder or anaconda, it gives error saying no module found.

please help

Installed CMake, visual studio c++, installed dlib through cmd.

Comment: How have you installed dlib? And have you tried running it from the normal python install

Answer (score 0):

Check what for dlib package if it is there in Anaconda:

```
conda list
```

If not then install the package using conda run:
[Reference link](https://anaconda.org/menpo/dlib)

```
conda install -c menpo dlib
```